# how to swap pictures form one div to another by clicking on the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have about five div(s), and each of them has a picture that is retrieved from database, i want when a picture is clicked on it moves to the main div and the picture on the main div replaces the one that was clicked in its div

```html
html code

<div id="viewPic1Div"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="viewPic2Div"><img src=""/></div>
<div id="ViewPic3Div"></div>
<div id="viewPic4Div"></div>
<div id="viewMainPicDiv"><img src=""/></div>
```

want when any of the picture in the div is clicked, it should be move to this  and the picture on this div replaces the picture in the div that was clicked. thanks

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that you tried.

Comment: You should post some javascript code, stackoverflow is not a begging site where you ask for code snippets to complete your projects. We are eager to help you, if you provide some code you wrote. If you are unsure what language to use in a specific case, I'd suggest going back to the beginnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("img").each(function(){
  var imgageClicked = $(this);
  imgageClicked.click(function(im){
    var srcMain = $("#viewMainPicDiv img").attr("src");
    var srcClick = (imgageClicked.attr("src"));
    
    $("#viewMainPicDiv img").attr("src",srcClick);
    imgageClicked.attr("src",srcMain);
  });
});
```

```css
img{float:left;with:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="viewPic1Div"><img src="http://es.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810038.png"/></div>
<div id="viewPic2Div"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icontexto/elite-captains/256/Elite-Captain-Black-Shielded-icon.png"/></div>
<div id="ViewPic3Div"><img src="http://graphichive.net/uploaded/fordesigner/1313308502.jpg"/></div>
<div id="viewPic4Div"><img src="http://www.icosky.com/icon/png/Avatar/Elite%20Soldiers%20Weapons/Gas%20Soldier%20with%20Weapon.png"/></div>
<div id="viewMainPicDiv"><img src=""/></div>
```

You don't need all the ids in the divs, just put a class to the images you want change and let the viewMainPicDiv and change the javascript code I post with `$("img.classYouChoose").each(f...` or follow the next snippet

```js
$("img.toswap").each(function(){
  var imgageClicked = $(this);
  imgageClicked.click(function(im){
    var srcMain = $("#viewMainPicDiv img").attr("src");
    var srcClick = (imgageClicked.attr("src"));
    
    $("#viewMainPicDiv img").attr("src",srcClick);
    imgageClicked.attr("src",srcMain);
  });
});
```

```css
img{float:left;with:100px;height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img class="toswap" src="http://es.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810038.png"/></div>
<div><img class="toswap" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icontexto/elite-captains/256/Elite-Captain-Black-Shielded-icon.png"/></div>
<div><img class="toswap" src="http://graphichive.net/uploaded/fordesigner/1313308502.jpg"/></div>
<div><img class="toswap" src="http://www.icosky.com/icon/png/Avatar/Elite%20Soldiers%20Weapons/Gas%20Soldier%20with%20Weapon.png"/></div>
<div id="viewMainPicDiv"><img src=""/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example: http://codepen.io/maxali/pen/PZQzmr

```
$('div[id^="viewPic"] img').click(function(){

    var picTemp = $(this).attr('src');
    var picMain = $('#viewMainPicDiv img').attr('src');

    $(this).attr('src', picMain); 
    $('#viewMainPicDiv img').attr('src', picTemp);
});
```